# How to make a window visible on all tabs

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows

How I can make a window automatically visible on all tabs ? Like [NerdTree-tabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) plugin:

```
:tabs
Aba 1
    NERD_tree_1
    main.c
Aba 2
    NERD_tree_1
    Makefile
Aba 3
    NERD_tree_1
>   readme.md
```

Comment: You read the plugin's source and use the same method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, @romainl's comment is a really good advice: you'll learn a lot by reading a real plugin code and trying to understand its behavior.

Now if you're new to vimscript and coding, it can be pretty hard. So here is a solution. *(It is probably more simple and maybe not as efficient as NERDTree way to do it but it should work properly)*

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:windowToKeep=[]

nnoremap <F2> :call SetWindowToKeep()<CR>
nnoremap <F4> :call OpenTab()<CR>

function! SetWindowToKeep()
    let g:windowToKeep = [expand("%:p"), winheight(0), winwidth(0)]
endfunction

function! OpenTab()
    execute "tabedit " . g:windowToKeep[0]
    execute "vsplit"
    execute "resize " . g:windowToKeep[1]
    execute "vertical resize " . g:windowToKeep[2]
endfunction
```

The idea behind this code is that "make a window visible on all tabs" is actually doing the following:

- Selecting a windows containing a buffer as the one you want to keep
- Then each time a new tab is created, it is splited to contain:

  - The selected window with the same buffer and the same size
  - Another window containing a new buffer

To do so, this code will create a variable `g:windowToKeep` which will contain the window that you want to keep.

To set this variable a mapping is done on <kbd>F2</kbd>: you'll have to press this key to set the window to keep on your tabs.

Then you can call the function `OpenTab()` either with ex mode or by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>. This function creates a new tab with a buffer you want to keep, split the tab and resize the window containing your buffer.

**Note 1** You can (of course) replace `<F2>` and `<F4>` by your favorite mappings.

**Note 2** It is possible that the function isn't exactly what you expected because your workflow can be a little different than what I imagined while creating the code. As it's a pretty simple code you should be able to tweak it to fit your needs more closely.

Comment: Maybe the variable you are referring to is `g:windowToKee`, not `g:bufferToKeep`.

Comment: @JairLopez: Obviously that was a typo, thanks for pointing it to me I edited the answer.